# How can I solve keyerror

Tags: keyerror, tfrecord

I'm studying the object detection in colab. 
I got the code from GitHub.
Here a link https://medium.com/@moshe.livne/training-tensorflow-for-free-pet-object-detection-api-sample-trained-on-google-collab-c2e65f4a9949

When I use create_pet_tf_record.py, there is an error.
It's KeyError.
I just have a class, and it is not same category.
Now, my class is Shin, but KeyError is 'drop'.
Actually, I used 'drop' category long time ago.

Can you solve these error

Code is running on the google colab.
my class is just one which is 'Shin'
I modified these code and I confirmed to run code for other images.

This is the code can create the tfrecord file.

```
%cd ~/datalab

!python ~/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py --label_map_path=label_map.pbtxt --data_dir=. --output_dir=. --num_shards=1
```

This  is my error

```
/root/datalab
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0615 10:23:11.859250 139781813761920 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py:318: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

W0615 10:23:11.859874 139781813761920 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py2.7.egg/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py:132: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

I0615 10:23:11.861181 139781813761920 create_pet_tf_record.py:273] Reading from Pet dataset.
I0615 10:23:11.861639 139781813761920 create_pet_tf_record.py:288] 21 training and 9 validation examples.
W0615 10:23:11.861834 139781813761920 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py2.7.egg/object_detection/dataset_tools/tf_record_creation_util.py:43: The name tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.io.TFRecordWriter instead.

I0615 10:23:11.862046 139781813761920 create_pet_tf_record.py:241] On image 0 of 21
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py2.7.egg/object_detection/utils/dataset_util.py:75: FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
  if not xml:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 318, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 305, in main
    mask_type=FLAGS.mask_type)
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 260, in create_tf_record
    mask_type=mask_type)
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 167, in dict_to_tf_example
    classes.append(label_map_dict[class_name])
KeyError: 'drop'
```

I have checked my label_map. I can see just one class 'Shin'

Can you know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That's an undefined class, you must to change from:

```
    classes.append(label_map_dict[class_name])
```

of File "/root/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py"
to:

```
    classes.append(label_map_dict[x])
```

being x the number of the file.pbtxt's class (in this case: 'drop').
except you were using that code for more than 1 class it will solve the problem.
I expect that it work, good lake.

Comment: I have the same Error please if someone have a best answer please don't pass.